# SoftXpand crashed Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

I installed SoftXpand on Windows 10 and immediately restarted my computer after the installation was completed. 
However, it crashed the Windows boot. 
Windows tries to repair itself but not seems to work. I can't even star in Safe Mode.

Does anyone know what could be the problem or how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: That is Windows 7 Software. Have you contacted the vendor for a certified Windows 10 compatible version?

Comment: I didn't. It was installed without checking the compatibilities versions. That's probably the reason it crashed. I would like to know how I could restore the Windows boot without actually restoring the Windows, if possible.

Comment: Probably at this point (No Safe Mode, No Boot, Repair does not work), you need to boot with a bootable USB key, recover your data and then reinstall Windows